# CSS rules changed with Javascript - effects visible in chrome but NOT ff or ie

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

My page should alternate hidden/shown `div`s based on the click of a button. This behavior works correctly in chrome, but not in other browsers.

My JavaScript adds an event listener for the click on each button. The event listener calls a function that changes the `className` for each of the 3 divs. Depending on which button is clicked, the divs get either the `invisible` or `visible` class.

For testing, I have uploaded a javascript snippet `alert(left_box.className);`
which CORRECTLY alerts me an alternating `content-box visible` & `content-box invisible`. So the rules are changing. It's just that these changed CSS rules are not SHOWING in Firefox and IE.

Help!

```js
var button_1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
var button_2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
var button_3 = document.getElementById('button-3');


var left_box = document.getElementById('left-box');
var center_box = document.getElementById('center-box');
var right_box = document.getElementById('right-box');


function one_clicked() {
    
    if (left_box.className == "content-box visible") {
        left_box.className = "content-box invisible"}
    else {
    
        left_box.className = "content-box visible";
    
        center_box.className = "content-box invisible";
        right_box.className = "content-box invisible";
        }
    alert(left_box.className);
};

function two_clicked() {
    
    if (center_box.className == "content-box visible") {
        center_box.className = "content-box invisible"}
    else {
        center_box.className = "content-box visible";
    
        left_box.className = "content-box invisible";
        right_box.className = "content-box invisible";
    }
    alert('hello');
};

function three_clicked() {
    
    if (right_box.className == "content-box visible") {
        right_box.className = "content-box invisible"
    }
    else {
    right_box.className = "content-box visible";
    
    center_box.className = "content-box invisible";
    left_box.className = "content-box invisible";
        }
    alert('fuckkkkkk');
};

button_1.addEventListener('click',one_clicked, false);
button_2.addEventListener('click',two_clicked, false);
button_3.addEventListener('click',three_clicked, false);
```

```css
body {
    margin:0px;
    background-color:coral;
    padding:3%;
}

.main-box {
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    height:75%;
    
}

.main-row {
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-between;
    
}

button {
    height:7%;
    width:25%;
    
}

.content-container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.content-box {
    width:25%;
    height:80%;
    background-color:bisque;
    border-radius:10%;
}


.visible {
    height:180%;
    width:150%;
}

.invisible {
    height:0.1px;
    background-color:transparent;
}


.footer{
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="expansion.css"></link>
        <title>Expansion</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="main-box"></div>
        
        <div class="main-row">
            <button id="button-1">1</button>
    
            <button id="button-2">2</button>
            
            <button id="button-3">3</button>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="content-container">
            
            
        
            <div class="content-box visible" id="left-box"></div>

            <div class="content-box invisible" id="center-box"></div>

            <div class="content-box invisible" id="right-box"></div>      
        
        </div>
        
         
<!--
        
        <footer>Footer</footer>
-->
     <script src="expansion.js"></script>
                

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the visible property and please refrain from the language

Comment: Umm why not just use jquery toggle()?

Comment: that it alerts you doesn't mean your code is correct.... but anyway the class changes work fine in firefox and even IE11, so maybe check your css. Btw, use your browser console (press F12 on most desktop browsers) for testing. They have an html tab where you can see the classes change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's working as intended. Because there's nothing in the `div`, it's completely collapsed and you can't see it. You'll notice once I put a span in, and changed the `background-color` to `display`, they show as expected.

```js
var button_1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
var button_2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
var button_3 = document.getElementById('button-3');


var left_box = document.getElementById('left-box');
var center_box = document.getElementById('center-box');
var right_box = document.getElementById('right-box');


function one_clicked() {

  if (left_box.className == "content-box visible") {
    left_box.className = "content-box invisible"
  } else {

    left_box.className = "content-box visible";

    center_box.className = "content-box invisible";
    right_box.className = "content-box invisible";
  }
  console.log('Left Box');
};

function two_clicked() {

  if (center_box.className == "content-box visible") {
    center_box.className = "content-box invisible"
  } else {
    center_box.className = "content-box visible";

    left_box.className = "content-box invisible";
    right_box.className = "content-box invisible";
  }
  console.log('Center Box');
};

function three_clicked() {

  if (right_box.className == "content-box visible") {
    right_box.className = "content-box invisible"
  } else {
    right_box.className = "content-box visible";

    center_box.className = "content-box invisible";
    left_box.className = "content-box invisible";
  }
  console.log('Right Box');
};

button_1.addEventListener('click', one_clicked, false);
button_2.addEventListener('click', two_clicked, false);
button_3.addEventListener('click', three_clicked, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 3%;
}
.main-box {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 75%;
}
.main-row {
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
button {
  height: 7%;
  width: 25%;
}
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.content-box {
  width: 25%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: bisque;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.visible {
  height: 180%;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: red;
}
.invisible {
  height: 0.1px;
  display: none;
}
.footer {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="expansion.css"></link>
  <title>Expansion</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main-box"></div>

  <div class="main-row">
    <button id="button-1">1</button>

    <button id="button-2">2</button>

    <button id="button-3">3</button>

  </div>

  <div class="content-container">



    <div class="content-box visible" id="left-box">

      <span>Left Box!</span>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box invisible" id="center-box"><span>Middle Box!</span>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box invisible" id="right-box"><span>Right Box!</span>
    </div>

  </div>


  <!--
        
        <footer>Footer</footer>
-->
  <script src="expansion.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Also note, instead of using `alert`, it's better to use `console.log`.